# Fireblocks API Client in C#

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, fireblocks-api

I am trying to use the Fireblocks API in a C# .net 6 application but there is no documentation for this.

I tried my keys using the [JavaScript example](https://developers.fireblocks.com/docs/javascript-guide#your-first-fireblocks-javascript-script), so I know they keys work.

I tried modelling a FireblocksHttpClient after the [Java example](https://developers.fireblocks.com/docs/java-guide#your-first-fireblocks-java-program) they gave, and what I came up with is below.
I installed the jose-jwt nuget package to get this done.

So far it's creating a jwt token but when I send a request I get "invalid exp value" as the response.

Can I get help updating the FireblocksHttpClient class so that it can work like the other examples?

Here's the code I have modelled after the [Java example](https://developers.fireblocks.com/docs/java-guide#your-first-fireblocks-java-program):

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class FireblocksHttpClient
{
    private readonly string baseUrl = "https://api.fireblocks.io";
    private readonly string apiKey;
    private readonly RSA privateKey;
    private readonly HttpClient client;

    public FireblocksHttpClient(string apiKey, string apiSecret)
    {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        client = new HttpClient();

        byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(apiSecret
            .Replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .Replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .Replace("\n", ""));

        var rsa = RSA.Create();
        rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(keyBytes, out _);

        privateKey = rsa;
    }

    public async Task<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject> Get(string path)
    {
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{baseUrl}{path}");
        req.Headers.Add("X-API-Key", apiKey);
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {SignJwt(path)}");

        using (var resp = await client.SendAsync(req))
        {
            var body = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(body);
        }
    }

    public async Task<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject> Post(string path, Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject data)
    {
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"{baseUrl}{path}");
        req.Headers.Add("X-API-Key", apiKey);
        req.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {SignJwt(path, data.ToString())}");
        req.Content = new StringContent(data.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (var resp = await client.SendAsync(req))
        {
            var body = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(body);
        }
    }

    private string SignJwt(string path)
    {
        return SignJwt(path, string.Empty);
    }

    private string SignJwt(string path, string dataJSONString)
    {
        using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
        {
            byte[] dataHash = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataJSONString));
            string bodyHash = BitConverter.ToString(dataHash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var expires = now.AddSeconds(55);

            var jwtClaims = new
            {
                sub = apiKey,
                iat = now,
                exp = expires,
                nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                uri = path,
                bodyHash
            };

            var jwtHeader = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "alg", "RS256" },
                { "typ", "JWT" }
            };

            var privateKeyParameters = privateKey.ExportParameters(true);
            var rsaParams = new RSAParameters
            {
                Modulus = privateKeyParameters.Modulus,
                Exponent = privateKeyParameters.Exponent,
                D = privateKeyParameters.D,
                P = privateKeyParameters.P,
                Q = privateKeyParameters.Q,
                DP = privateKeyParameters.DP,
                DQ = privateKeyParameters.DQ,
                InverseQ = privateKeyParameters.InverseQ
            };

            using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
            {
                rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

                var jwt = Jose.JWT.Encode(jwtClaims, rsa, Jose.JwsAlgorithm.RS256, extraHeaders: jwtHeader);
                return jwt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67023818/3363077.

My iat and exp in the JWT token needed to be set in unix timestamp in seconds.

So I updated the following section:

```
var jwtClaims = new
{
    sub = apiKey,
    iat = new DateTimeOffset(now).ToUnixTimeSeconds(),
    exp = new DateTimeOffset(expires).ToUnixTimeSeconds(),
    nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    uri = path,
    bodyHash
};
```

I'm leaving this question here in case anyone ever needs a FireblocksHttpClient  in C#.